# How can I access the API key in a heroku config var in a flask app?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm trying to get an app running that looks at an API, requiring a key. In flask itself, the key was in a file and called with `import from darwin_token.py`.

However, in trying to set this key to a Heroku config var, it seems to not allow me to actually perform the request.

I've got my API token set as `DARWIN_KEY` config variable as such:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

DARWIN_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
```

Here is my request:

```
response = requests.get("https://huxley.apphb.com/all/" + str(departure_station) + "/to/" + str(arrival_station) + "/" + str(user_time), params={"accessToken": DARWIN_KEY})
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
2019-03-07T19:49:08.744964+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
2019-03-07T19:49:08.744971+00:00 app[web.1]: requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://huxley.apphb.com/all/tth/to/ecr/['0821',%20'0853',%20'2147']?accessToken=None
2019-03-07T19:49:08.745592+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.149.119.251 - - [07/Mar/2019:19:49:08 +0000] "GET /test21 HTTP/1.1" 500 291 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"
2019-03-07T20:10:34.195893+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/test21" host=sheltered-citadel-80521.herokuapp.com request_id=1cd9044d-0ba8-4770-9d26-b5a46996b1b6 fwd="81.102.40.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=347ms status=500 bytes=456 protocol=https
```

Where am I going wrong? When I run the original flask program, it works fine.

Much appreciated!

Comment: The problem is not only your key, but also how you are encoding the user_time. However, haven't you confused SECRET_KEY with DARWIN_KEY?

Comment: Regarding the key, you are correct, `DARWIN_KEY` is my config var and I've changed this. However, I still keep getting `None` when I try to do `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DARWIN_KEY')`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the user_time encoding issue?

Comment: You just have to look at the generated URL in your console output.  `https://huxley.apphb.com/all/tth/to/ecr/['0821',%20'0853',%20'2147']` is definitely not correct; the API expects a comma-separated list of times, those square brackets, spaces and quotes shouldn't be there.

Comment: Appreciate the help! I think I've gotten it sorted using `formatted_times = ",".join(query_time)` to comma delimit these times values.